# How to run multiple selenium scripts from Django?

Tags: python, selenium, django-views

I've currently got two separate scripts that are using Selenium, one scrapes website A and returns a result, the other scrapes website B and returns a result. I would like to run the two scripts upon a button being clicked on my Django webpage. As far as I understand I should run my selenium scripts within a function in my views.py file of my Django project.

However, I am unclear of how I should do this, aside from pasting all the code from my selenium scripts into the views.py file which seems like quite a messy way to do it. Should I move my selenium scripts into my Django project and convert them to classes which can then be called from my views.py file as so:

```
def index(request):
    webpage_A = WebPageA() #This would be the name of the class where the first webscraper is run from
```

Apologies for the noob question, hoping someone can point me in the right direction in terms of best practice.

Comment: It seems you need some background task to make your work done. May be answers for these questions will give you a hand. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+background+tasks

Comment: I would recommend using something like celery to async process the selenium scraping task as it would unblock the request lifecycle. Selenium task can be heavy so you need a good system design for this one. You can refer to this article for general understanding [codeburst.io](https://codeburst.io/making-a-web-scraping-application-with-python-celery-and-django-23162397c0b6) to design a similar system

Comment: Thanks both, I'll have a read of them - codeburst.io looks like a good guide!